# With touches - how to stop UIIMageView moving when reaching a certain Y point

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an image at the bottom of the screen.

I want the user to to move the image upwards until it reaches a certain Y point as follows:

```
[door setCenter:CGPointMake(160,347)];
```

So far, as you drag the image (door) upwards it continues past my destination point but when you let go it snaps back to the correct position.

How do I stop the image moving when reaching a certain point if the user's finger is still swiping upwards? Would it be inside an if statement?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (startPoint.y < 347) {
         // something in here ?????
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"position = %f and  %f",startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
    [door setCenter:CGPointMake(160, startPoint.y)];
}  

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [door setCenter:CGPointMake(160,347)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting it in `touchesMoved` method. Something like,

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"position = %f and  %f",startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
    if (startPoint.y < 347) { //or suitable condition to verify your case
        [door setCenter:CGPointMake(160, startPoint.y)]; //then only set the center
    } else 
    { 
       [door setCenter:CGPointMake(160,347); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt work - As you swipe, the image still moves to the top of the screen until touchEnded. Any more ideas ??

Comment: How about adding `else { [door setCenter:CGPointMake(160,347); }` after the if block?

Comment: @barley, Thanks. I missed that part completely. pete, I have updated my answer with else part as well. Check it.

Comment: @ACB and Barley - Just added the else and it worked ! Thank you very much.